# python regex [:alpha:]

Tags: python, regex

I'm using this regex in Python:

```
import re

>>> ER = re.compile('^\w{0,30}$', re.U)

>>> ER.sub('.', 'Maçã')

>>>....
```

But a wanna catch only letters, [A-Z] does not work for me, because i need letters with accent .
Is there any way to use POSIX?  [:alpha:], something like that or another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified the regex - how about

```
ER = re.compile(u'^[^\W\d_]{1,30}$', re.U)
s = ER.sub(u'.', u'Maçã')
```

matches u'Maçã' but not u'Maçã01'.

Comment: "But [I] wanna catch only letters"

Comment: @Ignacio: fixed it - instead of \w, matches not-(not-\w or \d) - no non-alphanumerics or digits. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: It is exacty what i need! Thanks a lot! :)