# Regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

What is the regular expression that accepts all the words start with Alphabet only and reject all words having any occurrence of less than or more than three consecutive forward slashes (///) [if and only if slashes exist].

Example:

ABC2123_987 is allowed.

AV23DS///KOLJH is allowed.

But, the word FDG56/HJU is not allowed.

Also, FDG56////HJU is not allowed.

Comment: Have you written any code yet?

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is useful for testing Regular Expressions as you write them.

Comment: What if there are multiple occurrences of three forward slashes?

Comment: Then there are not exactly three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches any string beginning with an alphabetic, and containing zero slashes or exactly three consecutive slashes.

```
^[A-Za-z][^/]*(///[^/]*)?$
```

Comment: Are you sure ? `re.match(r'^[[:alpha:]][^/]*(///[^/]*)?$', 'FEZ///zefzf')` -> `None`...

Comment: Replace `[[:alpha:]]` with `[A-Za-z]` to fix what @Zulu pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, that's what you get for trying to be clever and portable across locales ... [`[^\W\d_]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800665/python-regex-alpha) would work for that, but it's decidedly obscure.

Comment: Thanks alot. re.compile(r"^[A-Za-z][^/]*(///[^/]*)?$") is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern

```
re.compile('(\w+(///)?)*')
```

A better pattern, as seen in the comments for this answer:

```
re.compile('^[a-zA-Z]\w*?(///)?(\w+(///)?)*$')
```

Comment: This will match foo///bar/// baz and 123.

Comment: @tripleee - I believe that matching foo///bar/// and baz matches the spec described. Matching 123 does not. I'm not sure of a clean way to handle that. Any suggestions?

Comment: `([A-Za-z]\w*(///)?)*`

Comment: @r3mus - that won't work if the three slashes are followed by a numerical character. ex. abc///1abc

Comment: Well, that wasn't in the criteria ;) "all the words start with Alphabet only" not words that have \w only after the ///

Comment: `[A-Za-z](\w*(///)?)*` works around that particular problem, but will accept bar////// etc.

Comment: I think this might solve the 'number after ///' and 'repeating ///' problems:`re.compile('[a-zA-Z]\w*?(///)?(\w+(///)?)*')`